# Does google's Crypto.JS AES encryption use PBKDF2 as default?

Tags: pbkdf-2

Does google's Crypto.JS AES encryption use PBKDF2 as default?

Some references, but I can't figure out the answer myself:

https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Cipher_Algorithms

https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/aes.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Cipher_Input) says it's `OpenSSL`, not PBKDF2:

> When you use a CipherParams object in a string context, it's automatically converted to a string according to a format strategy. The default is an OpenSSL-compatible format

This can be verified in the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/cipher-core.js#781). The implementation of the OpenSSL KDF is in [evpkdf.js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/evpkdf.js).

The key derivation function is usually referenced as `EVP_BytesToKey` which is the higher level function in the API that implements the KDF.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are invoking it like this:

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
```

As of 3.1.2 the default key derivation function is *OpenSSLKdf* as configured [here](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/cipher-core.js#785) and implemented [here](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/cipher-core.js#738) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/evpkdf.js).